# can't display two d3 charts at the same time in my angular app

Tags: angular, svg, d3.js, charts

I just added a second d3 chart as own component (like my first one) into my angular project. When I tried to display both on one of my pages, just the second one will (which needs some time to render) will stay on the page. The first one is barerly visible for about an half a second.

For both charts I created own components in which the charts (svgs) get appended to an own div with an unique id. I access the divs using ViewChild

I already tried to give both svg which will be rendered an unique svg id and variable name, like here:

```
const svgDoughnut = d3
.select(containerEl)
.append("svg")
.attr("width", containerEl.offsetWidth)
.attr("height", containerEl.offsetHeight)
.attr("id", "svgDoughnutChart")
.attr(
    "viewBox",
    -containerEl.offsetWidth / 2 +
        " " +
        -containerEl.offsetHeight / 2 +
        " " +
        containerEl.offsetWidth +
        " " +
        containerEl.offsetHeight
);
```

or here:

```
const element = this.lineChartContainer.nativeElement;
    const svgLine = d3
        .select(element)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", "svgLineChart")
        .attr("width", element.offsetWidth)
        .attr("height", element.offsetHeight);
```

But that didn't make any difference.

Comment: All id values must be unique.

Comment: Do you mean the svg ids? They are already unique :(

Comment: If you put two charts on the page, how many elements with id=svgDoughnutChart are there?

Answer (score 0):

For simple donut charts.
I created a *native* Web Component `<pie-chart>` that can be used in any framework

Every `<pie-chart>` is created in *shadowDOM*, so no issues with duplicate SVG `id` values

See https://pie-meister.github.io/  (unlicensed source code, free to do whatever you want with it)

##### Usage:

- define (or load) the (999 Bytes) `<pie-chart>` Web Component
- write semantic HTML

  ```js
  customElements.define("pie-chart",class extends HTMLElement{connectedCallback(){setTimeout((()=>this.svg(this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}))))}svg(t,e=(this.getAttribute("stroke")||"#3c3,#c33,#33c,#cc3,#c3c,#3cc").split(","),i=~~this.getAttribute("pull"),s=0,r=0){t.innerHTML=`<style>:host{display:inline-block}svg{width:100%}</style><svg part=svg viewBox=0,0,${1e3+i},${1e3+i}>${this.innerHTML}</svg>`;[...t.querySelectorAll("slice")].map(((t,u)=>{let l,o=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","g"),a=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text"),n=t.getAttribute("size")||"",h=~~n.replace("%",""),g=~~t.getAttribute("stroke-width")||~~this.getAttribute("stroke-width")||500+i/2-i,p=s;o.path=(s=0,u=g,a=t.getAttribute("stroke")||(l?"":e.shift()),n=h,b=p,A=(500+i/2)/2-i/2+s-("stroke-width"==this.getAttribute("fill")?(500-i/2-u)/2:0),c=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","path"))=>(c.setAttribute("part","path"),c.setAttribute("stroke",a),c.setAttribute("stroke-width",u),c.setAttribute("pathLength",r),c.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray",n+" "+(r-n)),c.setAttribute("d",`m${500+i/2},${500+i/2}m0,${-A}a2,2,0,000,${2*A}a2,2,0,000-${2*A}`),c.setAttribute("fill","none"),c.getPoint=(t=0,e)=>e?o.path(e).getPoint(t):c.getPointAtLength(c.getTotalLength()-c.getTotalLength()/r*(t+(b+n/2))),c);h==n?r||[...this.querySelectorAll("slice")].map((t=>r+=~~t.getAttribute("size"))):r=~~this.getAttribute("size")||100;h||(h=r-s,n=h+"%");l=o.path(~~t.getAttribute("radius"));o.points=[[0,0],[h/-2,g/-2],[h/-2,g/2],[h/2,g/-2],[h/2,g/2],[0,g/-2],[0,g/2],[0,~~t.getAttribute("pulltext")||~~this.getAttribute("pulltext")||0],[0,Math.abs(~~t.getAttribute("pull")||i)]].map((([t,e])=>l.getPoint(t,e)));o.setAttribute("part","slice"+u);o.setAttribute("size",n);o.setAttribute("label",a.innerHTML=this.querySelector("style")?t.innerHTML?t.innerHTML.replace("$size",n):n:"");l.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset","top"==this.getAttribute("offset")?h-r:s+=h);[...t.attributes].map((t=>l.setAttribute(t.name,t.value)));a.setAttribute("part","text");a.setAttribute("x",t.getAttribute("x")||("top"==this.getAttribute("offset")?"50%":o.points[7].x));a.setAttribute("y",t.getAttribute("y")||("top"==this.getAttribute("offset")?"50%":o.points[7].y));o.append(l,a);t.replaceWith(o);t.hasAttribute("pull")&&o.setAttribute("transform",`translate(${o.points[8].x-o.points[0].x} ${o.points[8].y-o.points[0].y})`)}))}});
  ```

  ```html
  <pie-chart stroke-width="200" pull="-50">
    <style>
      text {
        font-size: 4em;
        text-anchor: middle;
      }
    </style>
    <slice size="10"></slice>
    <slice size="20" pull></slice>
    <slice size="40"></slice>
    <slice size="40"></slice>
  </pie-chart>
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**My bad**

I found my error... Before creating a chart I removed the complete svg. So I could reuse the create function for rerendering when the window gets resized.

```
createChart(): void {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    ...
}
```

Because of that line of code I always removed the other chart which also got rendered in the same second.

**My fix:**

```
createChart(): void {
    d3.select("#svgDoughnutChart").remove();
    ...
}
```

I removed both charts via their appended unique id.